# ¿Cómo mantengo un menú abierto tras actualizar o cambiar de página en HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

Tengo un menú lateral que por defecto está oculto, al presionar cierto botón aparece.
Todo bien hasta ahí, pero me gustaría que al hace clic sobre alguno de sus elementos y cambiar o actualizar de página el menú se mantenga abierto.
Estas son las propiedades que tiene el menú.

```
<style>
.navegacionv {
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 220px;
        background-color: rgb(49, 58, 70);
        min-height: 600px;
        z-index: 5;
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        left: -100%;
        box-shadow: 10px 1px 10px #222222;
    }
</style>
```

Esta es la acción actual de mostrar u ocultar el menú

```
<script>    
var contador = 1;
    $("#btnmenu").click(function () {
        $(".hamburguesa").toggleClass('cruz');
        if (contador == 1) {
            $('.navegacionv').animate({ left: '0' });
            $('#fab').animate({ left: "250px" });
            $('#body').animate({ left: "220px", width: '1100px' });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            $('.navegacionv').animate({ left: '-100%' });
            $('#fab').animate({ left: "30px" });
            $('#body').animate({ left: "0", width: '100%' });
            contador = 1;
        }
    });
</script>
```

finalmente este es el código del menú en la pagina HTML(PHP)

```
<div class="navegacionv">
    <ul>
        <?php
        if ($estado == 1) {
            echo '
            <li><a href="./" id="home"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="cpanel"><i class="icon-cogs"></i> Administrar <i id="ic" class="icon iright icon-circle-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./categorias.php" id="categorias"><i class="icon icon-price-tags"></i> Categorias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./productos.php" id="productos"><i class="icon icon-drawer"></i> Productos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="user"><i class="icon icon-users"></i> Usuarios</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="ventas"><i class="icon-stats-bars2"></i> Ventas <i id="iv" class="icon iright icon-circle-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./regventas.php" id="registros"><i class="icon icon-stats-bars"></i> Registros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./regventas.php" id="registros"><i class="icon icon-stats-dots"></i> Ventas del día</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./sales.php" id="vender"><i class="icon icon-cart"></i> Vender</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="perfil"><i class="icon-user"></i> Perfil <i id="ip" class="icon iright icon-circle-down"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" id="mireg"><i class="icon icon-stats-bars"></i>&nbsp;Mis registros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="mydata"><i class="icon-book"></i>&nbsp;Mis datos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="logout"> <i class="icon-switch"></i> Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            ';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que buscas ?? -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311260/c%c3%b3mo-mantener-men%c3%ba-abierto-al-dar-clic-a-submen%c3%ba?rq=1

Comment: Algo así, utilizo el metodo de localstorage, hace una pequeña transision al comienzo, pero se mantiene abierto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para que se te abran las paginas en otra ventana puedes usar la propiedad

```
target="block"
```

en los enlaces.

Comment: No es como tal una propiedad sino un atributo

Comment: Y creo lo escribiste mal es `_blank`

Comment: Eso no es lo que necesitaba, pero de igual manera muchas gracias.